# selenium Action error

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate a mouse movement to an element, and I see that the method for doing so is something like:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver)
action.moveToElement(hoverElement)
```

However when I run this code I get a syntax error, and Pycharm is telling me Actions is an unreselved reference. I have also tried:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions
```

but I still get an error "no module named org." I am stuck, this code seems to work for everyone else, what's going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I find strange that a selenium package doesn't start with selenium.* and I find very strange your action declaration, that doesn't seem to be Python, are you following a tutorial ?  After a google search it looks like you're using java code in a Python IDE, I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, it is not `Actions`, it is [`ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) - imported this way:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Sample usage:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(elm).perform()
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!